# How to install offline packages on a linux server

Tags: software-installation

I need to install offline packages for a linux server.
it is a repellent task because all the time it outputs that the package I want to install needs several other packages.

How can I resolve this problem, please ?
Regards

Comment: Thank you but Keryx is using a graphical user interfcace which is not adequate for a server

Comment: There are other options too. Wait a minute....... why do you need to install software offline on a server? a server is meant to be always online, isn't it?

Comment: @RegisteredUser, There are several cases where a server is on a separate network that is completely inside a corporate firewall.  It's always on the isolated network and never on the public internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with [dpkg-offline](https://launchpad.net/dpkg-offline):

> dpkg-offline obtains a package's dependencies, starting from a known
>   set of packages (as for a base installation), fetches those .debs and
>   packages them up in a tarball. Ideal for offline installation of the
>   "seed" package.

First branch the project on launchpad:

```
bzr branch lp:dpkg-offline
```

### dpkg_offline tutorial

Let's say you want to create a tarball with all the dependencies
necessary to install `git` on an Ubuntu 12.04 server system.

Once you have `dpkg_offline`, ensure you have the needed dependencies
installed:

```
sudo apt-get install genisoimage mtools squashfs-tools apt-utils curl
```

Once they're installed, get your seed .iso image::

```
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.4-server-amd64.iso
```

Now you're all set to do the installation. Run this:

```
./dpkg_offline ubuntu-12.04.4-server-amd64.iso "git"
```

The first argument is the seed iso, while the second is a list of
packages to install. Using quotes is necessary so that the second
"thing" is taken as the whole list. Of course, it's **not** necessary if
you have only one seed package.

If the process completes successfully, a tarball will be left in the current
directory. The name will encode the seed ISO, creation date, and the base
packages that were installed:

```
apt-repo-ubuntu-12.04.4-server-amd64.iso-20131213-git_13a1.7.9.5-1_amd64.tar.gz
```

If something fails, `dpkg_offline` will tell you what failed and point you
to a log file that may contain more details about the failure. This file
will be in a temporary directory; `dpkg_offline` normally cleans this
directory up, but in the case of a failure it will leave it as-is for
analysis.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I read on the official documentation that dpkg does not resolve the dependencies problem.

Comment: And my problem is with the server edition, not the desktop one

Comment: This tools is called dpkg-offline but it uses the power of `apt` inside. We use it a lot for offline setup at Canonical

Comment: Just select a server iso in that case, it will work the same way.

Comment: I will try your solution

Comment: I've updated the tutorial using a server iso

Comment: And how can I do if my server has no internet connection since the start  and will never be connected to internet ?

Comment: All you need is an Ubuntu system connected from where you can download the server iso, it does not need to be a server. run dpkg-offline on this machine and copy the resulting tar.gz on a usb drive

Comment: It would have been better if you had posted this answer to the [question marked as duplicated](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline). Also note that `apt-offline` is already mentioned there.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa, `dpkg-offline` is not `apt-offline`, but I will update the question marked as duplicated. Thanks

Comment: Sylvain: there is no documentation on how to install dpkg_offline, not even a download link (i visited your page)

Comment: You have to branch it using `bzr branch lp:dpkg-offline`, I've edited my post. `sudo apt-get install bzr` if you don't have it installed.

Comment: Luís de Sousa : my question has nothing to do with your link because I deal with a server

Comment: it says: you have not informed bzr of your Lanched ID, but it is downloaded anyway,

Comment: Once dkg_offline is downloaded: can i use it directly with the command you gave me in the tutorial or must i perform something before that ?

Comment: If the package is not in a ppa but in Ubuntu archives, just download the server iso and give to dpkg-offline the name of the seed package, that's all

Comment: The list of arguments to give to dpkg_offline must be separated by a comma or a space, please ?

Comment: spaces, look at the README and tutorial here for further options if needed: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~roadmr/dpkg-offline/trunk/files

Comment: Sylvain, it is precisely because `apt-offline` is not `dpkg-offline` that I am calling your attention. Before posting an answer please make sure that the question is not a duplicate.

Comment: I am learning new things here Sousa, and I have been desperate to resolve this problem, and you are suggesting me GUI based stuff that is not performant and which I can not use anyway. The solution of Sylvain, if it works, is the best in the world.

Comment: when I run the command ./dpkg_offline my_server.iso "pkg1.deb pkg2.deb" it says to me that no squashes from iso found and that i am using an old server (which is true). How can i fix this trouble ? because i want to use that specific old server.

Comment: a 12.04 server or older?

Comment: For 12.04, indeed you can't use the iso. Please follow these [additional steps](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~roadmr/dpkg-offline/trunk/view/head:/README#L67) to get a tar.gz that can replace the ISO.

Comment: It is working. Thank you a lot and a lot, Sylvain.

Comment: Yes, older than 12.04

Comment: I know that the process is a bit long to set up for the first time but I'm happy to see that it worked for you. Upvote my answer (^) please.

Comment: I did already, 4 hours ago :) Thank you very much Sylvain.

Comment: Sorry, voting is not the same as accepting, you need to click on the ^ mark above the 0 (and the checkbox).

Comment: I am new to this website. I did what you asked me, hope it is correct. Thank you again very much for your help today.

Comment: Guys, can any of these comments be removed? They've kinda overflowed. Any important information should be edited into either the question or answer (as needed). Comments are meant to be (rather) temporary so if there is anything important here please make sure it gets edited into the correct place. Thanks.